# Error no match for operator, array of structs in C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and new to this site so please forgive any rookie mistakes I may make.
I'm working on a menu-driven program that takes the info of a book and then prints it down the line without having to use classes and vectors.
the issue that I'm having right now is that when I try to print the stored books, I get an error stating "no match for operator". I am stumped as of now, any help would be greatly appreciated.
The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void menu();
const int maxBooks = 1000;

struct bookInfo{
    
    string title;
    string author;
    int code;
    int year;
    
    
}book[maxBooks];

void insertRecord(int&, bookInfo&);
void deleteRecord();
void undeleteRecord();
void printBooks(int&, bookInfo&);
void searchForBook();

int main(){
    //bookInfo book[maxBooks];
//  bookInfo *pointer;
    
    menu();
        
    
    return 0;
}

void menu(){
    string choice;
    int tot;
    bookInfo para;
    bool done = true;
    
    cout<<"***********************" << endl;
    cout<<"Please enter a command:"<< endl;
    cout<<"'A': Add an entry" <<endl;
    cout<<"'D': Delete an entry"<<endl;
    cout<<"'U': Undelete an entry"<< endl;
    cout<<"'P': Print the books"<< endl;
    cout<<"'S': Search in the list"<<endl;
    cout<<"'Q': Quit"<<endl;
    cout<<"*********************** "<<endl;
    
    do{
        cout<< "Command: ";
        cin>> choice;
        
        if(choice == "a" or choice == "A")
        insertRecord(tot, para);
        
        else if(choice == "d" or choice == "D")
        deleteRecord();
        
        else if(choice == "u" or choice == "U")
        undeleteRecord();
        
        else if(choice == "p" or choice == "P")
        printBooks(tot,para);
        
        else if (choice == "s" or choice == "S")
        searchForBook();
        
        else if(choice == "q" or choice == "Q"){
        cout<<"it's been a pleasure " <<endl;
        done = false;
        }
        else cout<<"invalid input " << endl;
    }
    while(done);
        

}

void insertRecord(int& tot , bookInfo& book){
    
    tot++;
    
    cout<<"state the title of the book: "<< endl;
    cin>>book.title;
    
    cout<<"state the name of the author: "<< endl;
    cin>>book.author;
    
    cout<<"state the code: "<< endl;
    cin>>book.code;
    
    cout<<"state the publishing year of the book"<< endl;
    cin>>book.year;
    
    cout<<"you just added a book"<< endl;

    
}


void deleteRecord(){
    cout<<"it works2"<<endl;
}

void undeleteRecord(){
    cout<<"it works3"<<endl;
}

void printBooks(int& tot ,bookInfo& book){
    
//  bookInfo *pointer;
//  pointer = &book;
    if(tot == 0)cout<<"no books here boi"<<endl;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < tot ; i++){
    cout<<"Name of book " <<i+1 <<": "<< book[i].title<<endl;
    cout<<"Author of book " <<i+1 <<": "<< book.author<<endl;
    cout<<"Code of book " <<i+1 <<": "<< book.code<<endl;
    cout<<"Publication year of book " <<i+1 <<": "<< book.year<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    }
}

void searchForBook(){
    cout<<"it works5"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Your `printBooks` function can't seem to decide if it's printing a single `bookInfo` or an entire array of them. You pass it a single `bookInfo` object by reference, but then you iterate over it like it's an array, but then most of the time you ignore the array index and do stuff like `book.author` instead of `book[i].title`. What's supposed to be happening here?

Comment: If you are getting a compiler error, you should paste that error into the question verbatim. Also, you probably don't need 90% of the code you showed to reproduce the error, only relevant code, as a [mre] should be included.

Comment: I'd suggest trying to start smaller. Don't try to implement an entire menu item at a time. Focus on getting operations working correctly with a single `bookInfo` object. Can you write to one? Can you print from one? Once you're sure you can do basic operations on a single `bookInfo`, then start figuring out how to handle an array of multiple `bookInfo`s, and test the functionality of that.

Comment: You don't have to limit yourself to a statically sized "C" style array, this is C++ use std::vector<bookInfo> instead. Or std::list<bookInfo> if you want fast insert/delete of books from memory.

Comment: I can print from 1 with no issue, but the moment i add one more is when i get the error. i initially had the book.[i].author and others, i just removed em to lessen the number of error that was showing

Comment: I believe that 'int tot' is not initialized to zero.

Comment: Your code has [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) since you are using `tot` uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

You have array "book" on global scope and local parameter "book" that is structure.
Just remove parameter bookInfo& book from printBooks, you don't use it.
And put "book[i]" on every line (author, code, etc), not only for title.

About code-style: No need to use reference "&" type if parameter will not be changed and its size is small (like int). Also place const modifier if parameter by reference will not be changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot kind sir/mam, that seems to have solved it.